# ParserError: Error tokenizing data C error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to run this code which removes unnecessary columns from a dataframe for later processing. It loops through the first files then gives the error below. Before it was running fine. I saw something about it maybe being a corrupted file, so I deleted all previous files and have gone through producing all the files in the steps again, but I am still getting the error. Sorry if it is long winded, I need to show each step for my thesis and also I am still very much a novice programmer. Can anyone help with fixing this issue?

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = ('./Sketch_grammar/weighted/')
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    df = df.drop('Hits', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('Score', axis=1)
    df = df.drop('Score.1', axis=1)
    print(df)
    filename = os.path.splitext(file)
    (f, ext) = filename
    print(f)
    df.to_csv(path+'weighted_out/'+f+'_out.csv', index=False)
```

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sandra/git/trees/trees/remove_columns.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(path+file)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/sandra/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 539, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 737, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'
```

.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error suggests? `df = pd.read_csv(path+file, engine='python')`

Comment: Do you have any files in the folder which are not csv?

Comment: @Chris you'd be shocked at how many people don't read error messages, even when they say *exactly* how to fix their particular problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. I had read the error message, I am sorry I am a novice programmer and I don't always understand what is being asked of me. I was also confused by the fact that it works for the first files and then fails, although all the files have been produced by the same means. Thank you.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. The one below however did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is usually raised when the file read using pandas is either corrupted or not in a readable state.
Modifying code as below should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = ('./Sketch_grammar/weighted/')
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(path+file)
        df = df.drop('Hits', axis=1)
        df = df.drop('Score', axis=1)
        df = df.drop('Score.1', axis=1)
        filename = os.path.splitext(file)
        (f, ext) = filename
        df.to_csv(path+'weighted_out/'+f+'_out.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! So basically if it gives that and you know the files are OK, it is because Python isn't recognising what type of file they are?

Comment: If you know that the file isn't corrupted and the delimiter used in the text file i.e. a comma, a tab etc then there shouldn't be a problem. It's not that python is not recognizing the file type, it is that the read_csv function is not able to automatically find the seperator. [Read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thank you, your help has been very useful.